# Visual Studio (C++) 2019 doesn't inline functions in debug mode

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why the following simple code is not getting inlined in debug mode>

```
 __forceinline void DoInline()
 {
     printf("Hello world\n");
 }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    DoInline();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the disassembly:

[image]

I have tried all the options in the [Inline Function Expansion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ob-inline-function-expansion?view=vs-2019) and no matter what I try the disassembly shows a call to function.

Comment: Debug mode usually overrides inlining.

Comment: @KenY-N That's what I am trying to understand,if there a way to force debug mode not to override inlining? I want to inspect some of my methods in disassembly to see if those are actually inlined by the compiler or not.

Comment: Out of interest why do you need to know if functions are inlined in debug mode? There are several options used in debug mode that will disable inlining. I think you should just disassemble the release mode code.

Comment: @AJR during code review with developers. You mean I should switch to release and enable debug symbols to be able to set breakpoints.Right?

Comment: VS (as well as any other sane debugger) offers commands to step into, step over, step out. For all these commands, the debugger needs/uses the stack frames and/or `call` and `ret` commands to achieve this. Hence, inlining is suppressed in debug mode because, due to inlining, these were not generated into code. (I once in the past accidentally tried to debug something where inlining was not suppressed. That was a nightmere...) ;-)